# Which producer configuration combination should be faster when combining `enable.idempotence` and `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`?

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

When **duplication is permited, but ordering must be guaranteed**, what producer configuration combination is expected to be faster?

```
enable.idempotence = true
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
```

or

```
enable.idempotence = false
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
```

?

From my understanding in reading the Kafka documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939661/does-enabling-idempotence-on-a-kafka-producer-decrease-throughput) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49982786/ordering-guarantees-when-using-idempotent-kafka-producer) question, to ensure records ordering we have the above two options.

The first will also ensure deduplication, with a higher in-flight request. The deduplication would add a slight performance overhead, but since I can set a higher in-flight request I would expect it to be faster than the second option.

Which one should be faster?

Comment: Use the included Kafka producer perf test scripts and find out

Comment: Cab you point me to them, please? I am not aware of it.

Comment: Open your kafka install folder, and look for `bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh`